# dataUrl of svg to blob svg

Tags: image, svg, blob

I'm using domtoimage in order to get dataUrl of svg.

Next I want to create blob of svg type in order to save an svg file.
All my search ends with the option to draw canvas and from it to get the blob. But canvas returns 'image/png' type and no matter what I did I couldn't get an svg type.

```
return domtoimage.toSvg(el, {quality: 0.9, dpi: 96})
      .then(dataUrl => {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
          const img = new Image();
          img.src = dataUrl;
          img.onload = () => {

            const elem = document.createElement('canvas');
           
            const ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
            const data = ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
            const imgBlob = this.base64ImageToBlob(data);
            selectedMap.newImageFile = new File([imgBlob], dataUrl, {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
            this.updateMapInService(selectedMap, maps);
            res();
          };
        });
      });
```

Comment: @RobertLongson My DOM is not SVG. I use domtoimage in order to get an svg file of my DOM

Comment: Isn't your input dataUrl an SVG image? Add its value to the question so we can see.

Comment: Your ``imgBlob`` is binary data of (Canvas) **pixels**, they are not (SVG) **vectors**. If you can save pixels to vectors you have found the Holy Grail.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have  containing  (or just ) and you want to make Blob from this (or any Data URL) is quite simple as:

```
const SVG_Data="data:image/svg+xml,"+encodeURIComponent(SVG_DOM_Element.outerHTML);
```

This is the structure of DataURL of an SVG, fit for use anywhere.
To make a blob from this:

```
const bf=new Blob(
    new Uint8Array.from(
        SVG_DataURL.split("").map(function(c) {
            return c.charCodeAt(0);
        })
    ),
    "image/svg+xml"
);
```